# Panda DataFrame not get update

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, updates

I'm trying to update my dataset randomly as follows

```
originaldata = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
for i in range(10):
    timeslot = random.randint(1, 10) 
    percentage = random.randint(1, 101) / 100 + 1
    originaldata.iloc[i][timeslot] *= percentage
```

But interestingly it runs but dataset never gets updated. Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `originaldata.iloc[i,timeslot] *= percentage
`

Comment: Yeah, this worked Thanks :). But what is wrong with my approach? :/

Comment: Do not chain iloc with [], that will raise the unknow error (without warning error message )

Answer (score 1):

What's the version of your pandas? I tried `pandas 0.23.4` with following code:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: import numpy as np
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5, 3)))
```

so the input dataframe is:

```
In [4]: df
Out[4]:
   0  1  2
0  5  6  3
1  6  0  9
2  6  3  5
3  7  0  0
4  4  1  9
```

and after `*=` operating:

```
In [5]: df.iloc[0][1]*=2
In [6]: df
Out[6]:
   0   1  2
0  5  12  3
1  6   0  9
2  6   3  5
3  7   0  0
4  4   1  9
```

and we can see that the element `df[0, 1]` is converted from `6` to `12`.

and @Wen-Ben 's answer may work when the column names of `timeslot` are the same with the column numbers:
`originaldata.iloc[i,timeslot] *= percentage`